# Blender API remove polygons from mesh

Tags: python, materials, scripting, faces

I try remove polygon by `material_index`. Re-assign polygons errors

```
    new_polys = []

    for polys in me.polygons:
        if polys.material_index == 1:
            new_polys.append(polys)

    me.polygons = new_polys
```

`AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "polygons" from "Mesh" is read-only`

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be in python? I understand if you need to automate it because you have lots of objects or lots of materials.

Comment: yes of course, I need it in python. I have about 4k objects in my scene, it's impossible to do it manually.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do but based on your first sentence phrase *"remove polygons by material_index"* it sounds like you want a script that removes all faces that have material index = 1. so i'm not sure why you are trying to assign those faces you want to remove back to the mesh. it's non sensical :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all polygons or faces with `material_index = 1`, Select all objects you want and run the script:

```
import bpy

material_index = 1

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for face in obj.data.polygons:
        face.select = (face.material_index == material_index)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
```